# Logon script to log local administrators except Administrator and Domain Admins

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am using

```
net localgroup "Administrators" > \\server1\localadmins\%computername%.txt
```

in a logon script at the moment which generates a log file like

```
Alias name     Administrators
Comment        

Members

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Administrator
DOMAIN\dave
DOMAIN\Domain Admins
DOMAIN\jim
DOMAIN\john
sally
The command completed successfully.
```

but actually I only want to know when domain users are local administrators.

100's of computers just report

```
Alias name     Administrators
Comment        

Members

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Administrator
DOMAIN\Domain Admins
The command completed successfully.
```

but is perfect so I don't want to know about these. Is there some method that I can only generate a log file if a `DOMAIN\` user except `DOMAIN\Domain Admins` is listed?

Comment: Do you still want to show `Alias name Administrators`, `Comment` and `Members` in the output?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps just use `findstr -v` to exclude certain results.

```
net localgroup "Administrators" | findstr -v "Domain Admins" | findstr "DOMAIN\"
```

This will search for `DOMAIN\` but exclude `Domain Admins`.

So as in your fist example, running above should give you:

```
DOMAIN\dave
DOMAIN\jim
DOMAIN\john
```

or if you want to display local users `Administrator` and `Sally` as well, then just do:

```
net localgroup "Administrators" | findstr -v "Domain Admins" |
```

Comment: Awesome. I will give this a shot. Didn't know about `findstr`. Does this still create an (empty) file when there are no users?

Comment: Correct yes. File will be empty if nothing matches